# After domain rename - can't connect to vmware server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere

I have renamed our domain (server 2012) - the entire process passed successfully.

I am trying to access our VSphere - with no success.

The error I receive is:

**Failed to connect to VMware Lookup Service - https://VCSRV.DOMAIN:7444/lookupservice/sdk**

The DOMAIN is the OLD domain name - I assume I need to change that. But I can't access/login with any user.

The machine: VCSRV (windows server 2008 r2) has been joined to the new domain as member server.

Our vsphere is installed on a windows client VCSRV (it's NOT an app).

We do not use SSO

In old APP we had, there was some management console, where's that on the windows version?

Comment: Reinstall Virtual Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a messy situation.

A domain rename is an intrusive process. It's certainly not something to take lightly, especially if mail servers, client computers, etc. are involved. I'm not sure why the VMware fallout was not planned for.

Depending on your VMware vSphere version (you did not specify), the SSO component is critical to Active Directory integration. SSO changed considerably between vSphere 5.1 an 5.5. Either way, I'd really recommend reinstalling vCenter because you don't know what bindings exist to the old domain name. Consider a move to the vCenter Server Linux-based appliance for simplicity and forward compatibility.